# AWS Cognito - Credentials Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to use AWS Cognito to authenticate (using Google) and authorise users, with the intention of assigning IAM roles for the authorised users.

I have followed the below steps till now

1. Use the authorization end point to fire up Google OAuth process
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html

   > I am using "Grant flow"
   >   I receive a such as `code=b3e8bca6-5a01-45db-b4c6-cd6900d0xxxx`
2. Make a post request to oath/token http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

   > I receive the following information:

   ```
   "id_token": "eyJraWQiOiJJR2NVdHJcL3pOa3pQK1lre...........",
   "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiJCbWx0cjJvMnJlVGhHW..........",
   "refresh_token": "eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOi............",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "token_type": "Bearer"
   ```
3. Try to fetch the AWS credntions using the CognitoIdentityCredentials

   ```
   AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
       IdentityPoolId: environment.identityPoolId, // Federated ID eu-west-2:af47703f-350c-4018-ae6a-xxxxxx
       RoleArn: environment.roleArn,// IAM role
       Logins: { 'accounts.google.com': data.id_token },
   });

   AWS.config.getCredentials((error) => {
       if(error) console.log("Error: ", error);
       this.creds = AWS.config.credentials;
   });
   ```

> I get a bad request 500 error

```
{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName"}
```

Couple of questions

1. Is the sequence of steps followed correct?
2. How to I get a CongnitoUserId ? `id_token` is a very long string, but not sure what information can I extract from it?
3. Finally how to I get accessKey to make AWS calls?

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the sequence of steps followed correct?

I believe so.

> `id_token` is a very long string, but not sure what information can I extract from it?

Both the `id_token` and `access_token` are [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/)s.  You can base64 decode the strings in between the dots to extract the token's contents.  Typically we're concerned with the middle section, or *payload*.

You can paste these tokens into a decoder like [this one](https://jwt.io/), and view the contents in your browser.  In javascript, [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) works as you'd expect.

I'm not sure what user id you're after, but if the username suffices, the id_token contains a `cognito:username` key.

> Finally how to I get accessKey to make AWS calls?

Change the provider in your `Logins` map.

If you were talking directly to Google, as opposed to talking to Google through Cognito (via `/oauth2/authorize`), you would use `accounts.google.com` in the `Logins` map as your example shows.

However, the tokens you're getting back are from Cognito, not from Google.  Both tokens contain an `iss` (issuer) key, which is (most likely) your User Pool Id. This is the value you should use in the `Logins` map.  Assuming the issuer is your User Pool:

```
Logins: {
    'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxx': token
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! I am able to decode the token and have corrected the Logins map using the iss key mentioned above but I still get the same error message {"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName"}. By "token" in the Login maps I assume you are referring to id_token.

Comment: Below are my id_token details "identities": [
    {
      "userId": "1068...",
      "providerName": "Google",
      "providerType": "Google",
      "issuer": null, // << Is the issue and provider mismatch because of this ??
      "primary": "true",
    }
  ],

Comment: Thanks ! Finally managed to get it working, I had to strip out https:// from the iss key.

Comment: @maxkart which token do you use for `data.id_token` ?

Comment: @TeddyKossoko i don't understand your questions,.. there are three tokens id, access and refresh .. i used id for user details and access for authorization